# Network Information to Listview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, listview

Hi guys I am trying to get the information on the active connection to listview.

So far I have:

```
Dim allProcess As String
Dim sl As String = "ProcessSplit"
Dim ipProps As System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
For Each connection As System.Net.NetworkInformation.TcpConnectionInformation In ipProps.GetActiveTcpConnections
  Dim LEP As String = connection.LocalEndPoint.ToString
  Dim REP As String = connection.RemoteEndPoint.ToString
  Dim CState As String = connection.State.ToString
Next
```

How can I get a new row entry for every connection? Sorry I am just starting out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your For Each loop, just add the ListView adding code:

```
Dim data(3) as String
Dim itm as ListViewItem
For Each connection As System.Net.NetworkInformation.TcpConnectionInformation In ipProps.GetActiveTcpConnections
  Dim LEP As String = connection.LocalEndPoint.ToString
  Dim REP As String = connection.RemoteEndPoint.ToString
  Dim CState As String = connection.State.ToString
  data(0) = LEP
  data(1) = REP
  data(2) = CState
Next

itm = New ListViewItem(data)
ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
```